# How to access CommandBar controls from Frame

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to dynamically access my `CommandBar` from frames to control its back button. How can I ensure the `CommandBar` back button is hidden on the first frame (Frame1) whilst being visible and clickable on the second frame (Frame2)?

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <CommandBar>
            <CommandBar.Content>
                <Button
                Click="Back_Click" 
                x:FieldModifier="public"
                Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}" 
                Name="BackButton" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            </CommandBar.Content>
        </CommandBar>

        <Frame Name="MyFrame"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.cs**

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Current = this;

        Frame_Main.Navigate(typeof(Frame1));
    }

    public static MainPage Current;

    private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        On_BackRequested();
    }

    private bool On_BackRequested()
    {
        if (this.Frame.CanGoBack)
        {
            this.Frame.GoBack();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void BackInvoked(KeyboardAccelerator sender, KeyboardAcceleratorInvokedEventArgs args)
    {
        On_BackRequested();
        args.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

**Frame1.cs**

```
public sealed partial class Frame1: Page
{
    public Frame1()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MainPage.Current.BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

**Frame2.cs**

```
public sealed partial class Frame2: Page
{
    public Frame2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MainPage.Current.BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        MainPage.Current.BackButton.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access the Back Button from Frame1 and Frame2, you could try to set the `x:FieldModifier` of BackButton as **public**. In this case, it will be public and you can access the button by its x:name from other pages. In addition, it's better to put the click event in the MainPage instead of Frame2. For example:

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <CommandBar>
        <CommandBar.Content>
            <Button x:FieldModifier="public" Click="Back_Click" Name="BackButton" Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </CommandBar.Content>
    </CommandBar>

    <Frame Name="MyFrame" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

You need to define a public static MainPage instance to let other pages access your button through this instance.

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    Current = this;
    MyFrame.Navigate(typeof(Frame1));
}

public static MainPage Current;

private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    On_BackRequested();
}

private bool On_BackRequested()
{
    if (MyFrame.CanGoBack)
    {
        MyFrame.GoBack();
        return true;
    }
        return false;
}

private void BackInvoked(KeyboardAccelerator sender, KeyboardAcceleratorInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    On_BackRequested();
    args.Handled = true;
}
```

**Frame1.cs:**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MainPage.Current.BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

**Frame2.cs:**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    MainPage.Current.BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    MainPage.Current.BackButton.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

**Or** you can define a property to **bind** with the Visibility of Button, when you navigate to next page, you can pass the property in the Navigate method(e.g. `Frame_Main.Navigate(typeof(Frame1), VM);`) and then in the OnNavigatedTo event to change its value.

Comment: The visibility part works, but the click event doesn't. See updated code.

Comment: Have you subscribed the click event of Button in MainPage.xaml?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Like this: `<Button Name="BackButton" Click="Back_Click" x:FieldModifier="public" ....../>`. You need to add the Click event to the Button, then the Back_Click in the MainPage.cs can be triggered. After that, you can call the GoBack() method in the Back_Click event. You can check the above code snippent about MainPage part.

Comment: When the Back_Click event is triggered, you didn't call the GoBack() method in the Back_Click of MainPage, please add the On_BackRequested(); method to your MainPage instead of Frame2 page. Please refer to the above code snippet in my MainPage.xaml.cs.

Comment: Or if you still want to achieve the GoBack() method in the Frame2 page, you can subscribe the click event of BackButton. When leave the Frame2 page, release the event. For example: `protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            MainPage.Current.BackButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            MainPage.Current.BackButton.Click += Back_Click;
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
            MainPage.Current.BackButton.Click -= Back_Click;
        }`

Comment: How about disabling one of the AppBarButtons?